# Double integral calculation where $x=(y-1)^{2}-1$ and $y=x$. Not sure whether I should do it in terms of $y$ or $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

This is what it looks like:

[image]

My first strategy was to separate it into two by drawing a vertical line at x=0 and calculate the first half in terms of x first, and the second half in terms of y first. But I was still left with variables in the end.  Halp?

Comment: For the left half, the bounds on x would be -1 to 1, and y would be 0 to 2(sqrt(x+1)+1). FOr the right half, the bounds on y would be y=sqrt(x+1)+1 and y=x.

Comment: It should be $\displaystyle \int \limits_{-1}^0\int \limits_{-\sqrt{x+1}+1}^ {\sqrt{x+1}+1}xy\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$ on the 'left'.

Comment: Oops, yeah that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $y\in[0,3]$ and that $(y-1)^2-1=y(y-2)$ and write the integral over $y$. The integral writes
$$d=\int_0^3\left(\int_{y(y-2)}^{y}xy\,\mathrm dx\right)\mathrm d y
=\int_0^3y\left[\frac12\left(y^2\right)-\frac12\left(y(y-2)\right)^2\right]\,\mathrm dy.$$
From this point you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Uhh Wolfram says that's not integrable.

Comment: @Bob. You may have made a mistake with Wolfram Alpha because it is polynomial... and the result is $3^5/40$ by the way (found ``by hand'').